# expanding --vg-root(dm-0)

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

I added more space to my Ubuntu VM through vSphere (to 1TB). Then, I used GParted from Ubuntu live CD to expand sda2, and sda5. But when I do `lsblk` my root partition (--vg-root(dm-0)) is still the same (345.7G) instead of ~1020G. But I can see the "parent" sd5 as ~1TB.

How can I expand the --vg-root (dm-0)?

I still have a snapshot that I can go back to if needed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to expand it using `lvextend -L +XG /dev/HOSTNAME-vg/root`

As seen [here](http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/168-resizing-the-disk-space-on-ubuntu-server-vms)

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing to add to the above (worked for me in Proxmox pve where my docker VM was running out of dm-0 space) is to do both the above and then:

```
resize2fs yourLogicalVolumeName
```

So, the total to expand for me was:

```
lvdisplay
```

1 make note of the name and path to your logical volume

2 do below replacing 'X' with the number of GB you're expanding by. In my case this was 15GB, so '+XG' below became '+15G'.

```
lvextend -L +XG yourLogicalVolumeName
```

Then

```
resize2fs yourLogicalVolumeName
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).